# When linking to GitHub, what's the policy on permalinks (specific commit) vs up-to-date info (master)?

Tags: support, hyperlinks, github

E.g. see [suggested-edits/22923009](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/22923009) which changes `https://github.com/…/33d6380103576782901c208e68488cc0b5af433b/…` to `https://github.com/…/master/…`.

I intentionally put a GitHub permalink in the original answer, as I was worried that link might break with newer commits. On the other hand, it's easier to notice a broken link than some outdated information, so "latest or broken" might be a better state than "outdated but not broken". So I see their point as well.

What is the recommended approach in these cases?

Comment: Any posts should be self contained, regardless of links.

Comment: It is self-contained (as in I gave a summary of what the link says), but people might find detailed information provided by the link to be more useful.

Comment: I'd be inclined to go with the permalink, because it shows the content as it was when the answer was created.  As the content of the repository is changed, what's viewable via the master link can grow away from what the answer refers to, resulting in a link that is not (directly) relevant to the answer.  But that would depend on the specifics of the question, answer, and repository.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You generally should use the specific commit revision *if* you are referring to a specific commit or something that might change in the future. I have seen many links to Github that were made obsolete and useless because of an update. Checking the date something was posted and looking for the specific commit from that date wastes a lot of time.